# How to find out the version of a chef server

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef server that I'm pretty sure is chef 10. I don't remember the exact version and it doesn't seem to say it anywhere in the web ui. Does anyone know how I can find out what it is? I don't see it in any configuration files either, but maybe I'm not looking in the right place.

Thanks.

Comment: I have Chef 11 and there is a version-manifest.txt in Chef server installation folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So to determine chef-server version:

If there's a couchdb running it's chef10, you may ensure that listing `/var/lib/couchdb/*` seeing recent files and in the processlist (unless it's the old base from an update not cleaned properly but in this case the files should not be recent)

In this case the version of the chef server is given by:

```
cat /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/chef-server/version.rb
```

If there's no couch db, you're on chef11 or chef12, for chef11 on unbutu the version manifest is in `/opt/chef-server/version-manifest.txt`.

Comment: Thanks. Mine was at `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/lib/chef/version.rb` but I found it by doing `find / -name version.rb` and a vgrep on the result.

Comment: This means it's a gem install of chef server, not really supported for upgrades, see knife-backup plug-in for an upgrade (dump of all objects. Nodes, roles, env, etc. To be retrieved uploaded after) do a pass at chef-server 11.1 before going to 12 to avoid acl problems when you'll upgrade to chef-server 12

Answer (score 41):

Inside your Chef installation directory you will find a file named version-manifest.txt, it has information about different applications versions, the first line refers to the chef-server's version. In CentOS 6 you can do this:

```
# head -n1 /opt/opscode/version-manifest.txt
chef-server 12.0.0
```

Comment: i find it hard to believe that there's no CLI to get the version of chef server. but, here we are.

Answer (score -3):

Another method:

Type `chef-shell` and then type `version`

Comment: in this answer you are assuming that `chef-shell` is properly configured, that is not the case every time, especially for people new to chef.

Comment: This return by default the chef-client version, not the server one. And they are unrelated.

Answer (score -3):

This command will give you the Chef Server version from any Chef client, in case you don't want to log into the server. It also works on the server:

```
$ chef-shell --version
Chef: 12.4.1
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, by default this will return the chef-client version. (I'm even unsure this could return the chef-server version at all)